# Install ASP.NET MVC3 and MVC2 side by side?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

Can you install ASP.NET MVC3 and MVC2 side by side?

I want to install MVC3 and try it out on a smaller project.  BUT I want to retain our current large project on MVC2 for a little while.

If I install MVC3, will my existing project be automatically upgraded or do I have the option to keep it on MVC2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Question title says it all: Can you install ASP.NET MVC3 and MVC2 side by side?

You can perfectly fine have ASP.NET MVC 2 and 3 running side by side on the same machine. In VS2010 you have the possibility of choosing which version you want when creating new projects and on the production server you can have MVC 2 and 3 applications running side by side without any problems. Just don't forget that MVC 3 implies .NET 4.0 whereas MVC can run on both .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0 application pools.

Comment: @JK, well, no problems then. Both can work side by side. The machine I am writing this comment at the very moment has MVC 1,2,3 running side by side on VS 2010, .NET 4.0 without any issues.

Answer (score 5):

MVC 3 and 2 can exist side-by-side. The project file will not / does not have to be upgraded.
For more details, see http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I have MVC2 and MVC3 installed on my development machines. When you start new projects you are prompted for both MVC versions to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but:

I had a problem with NUnit because some of the classes are defined in both versions of the System.Web.Mvc dlls. The applications run fine, but an NUnit looses its mind - it blows up with a message Cannot cast SelectedList to SelectedList.

**Edit**

I am running NUnit 2.5.5. Whats happening is that when the application is built it is using the version 3.0.0.0 of the dll, but when it is run under NUnit by the time it loads the app dll, the 2.0.0.0 version of the dll is already loaded. Both of them have the SelectedList class defined in them and that causes the NUnit to loose its mind